# Closed and Connected subgroups of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, connectedness

Question is  :

What are closed connected subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$ and from that deduce what are closed connected subgroups of $\mathbb{R}^n$

What i have done so far is :

Only connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are singletons and intervals..

As i need my connected sets to be closed i need closed intervals (singletons are already closed)

Choose $A=\{a\}$ for $a\neq 0$...

If we want $A$ to be subgroup then we need $\{na : n\in \mathbb{Z}\}\subset A$ which is not possible

Thus, only closed connected singleton is $\{0\}$

Now choose $A=[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$.. As $b\in [a,b]$ and if we want this to be subgroup we need $\{nb : n\in \mathbb{Z}\}\subset A$ which is not possible.

Thus there is no bounded closed connected subgroup...

So, only closed connected subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$ are $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}$

I am not very sure about how should i deduce about closed connected subgroups of $\mathbb{R}^n$..

I somehow guess that only such subgroups are $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$  but i am not sure..

I would be thankful if some one can give some hints to workout this..

EDIT :

I have tried to show that this is indeed a subspace..

For $H$ a closed connected subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$ Suppose $x,y\in H $ then as $H$ is a subgroup $ax\in H$ and $by\in H$

Then i immediately wanted to write $ax+by\in H$ (hoping that closed and connected implies path connected )  which would imply $H$ is a subspace and everything would go so smoothly as there are only finitely many subspaces..

But then i realized closed and connected does not imply path connectedness...

I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: subspaces are closed subgroups.

Comment: For the singletons case just note that any subgroup *must* contain $0$, and so can only contain $0$.

Comment: @martini : Ok, So, copies of $\mathbb{R}^k$ are closed connected subgroups for $k<n$.. Can i get any other subgroups..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : Yes Yes.. i got it :)

Comment: Martini gave the hint: linear subspaces. Like the line $x=y$ in the plane, etc. And strictly speaking, $\mathbb{R}$ is not even a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : what i mean is copy of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$... line $x=y$ has correspondence with $\mathbb{R}$.. So, can i say any linear subspace comes in this form

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Not just any copy, a linear subspace copy...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : yes yes... linear subspace copy

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : So, can i say only closed connected subgroups are linear subspace copies of $\mathbb{R}^k$

Comment: You still have to prove that!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma :  I do not know how to start this... suppose $A$ is closed connected  subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^2$ then...  As it is subgroup it can not be bounded.... i am not able to see more than that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15624/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-praphulla-koushik).

Comment: Did you already solve the problem in 1-dimensional case? If you did, then you should next verify that a closed connected subgroup of $R^n$ is stable under multiplication by real scalars. The last step then is to read the definition of a linear subspace of a vector space.

Comment: @studiosus : i could show that it is stable under multiplication by real scalars just for subgroups we do not need closed connected.... but for addition of two such vectors we need path contentedness which is what i am trying to bring in..

Comment: I guess in the general case you could also try taking a maximal subspace $V$ contained in your group, and then pass to the quotient $\Bbb{R}^n/V$: the quotient topology is what you expect it to be, the projection of a connected group is a connected group, ...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : I am sorry i did not get what you have said :O

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this is an overkill, but you can prove this with Lie theory: The Lie algebra of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the exponent is the identity. If $G$ is a closed connected subgroup then its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\exp\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}$ generates $G$. But $\mathfrak{g}$ is already a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $G=\mathfrak{g}$ and it is a subsapce.